change the main text font of cleanthesis templete
How can I ? I tried to modify commands in sty file but it dosent work.

Welcome! Please: never post pictures of code. It cannot be searched, indexed or copy-pasted for testing and is useless to people who depend on screen-reading software. Always cut and paste code and messages as plain text and format using the {} or ctrl-k (or the Mac equivalent) or whatever. Please also tell us what you tried and what 'doesn't work' means. Did you get an error? Unexpected output? Or ...?

It neither not change the font style nor give an error
